# I want to remove "continue reading..." in rss feed

Tags: rss

I want to remove "continue reading..." in rss feed.

Which php file should I change and which code should I edit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add code on your functions.php at last. After update check feed url remove browser cache.

```
function custom_auto_excerpt_more( $more ) {
    return '...';
}
add_filter( 'excerpt_more', 'custom_auto_excerpt_more' );
```

[image]